# React: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Please Help me

Here is my code (error message seems to think something is wrong with line 7):

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

```
4 | import axios from 'axios';
5 | const App = () => {
6 | 
7 |   const spotify = Credentials();
8 |   console.log('READING APP.JS');
```

This my code :App.JS

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Dropdown from './Dropdown';
import {Credentials} from './Credentials';
import axios from 'axios';
const App = () => {

  const spotify = Credentials();
  console.log('READING APP.JS');
  const data=[
    {value: 1, name:'A'},
    {value: 2, name:'B'},
    {value: 3, name:'C'},
]
```

File :Credentials.js

```
const Credentials = () => {

    return {
        ClientId: 'ac1c364eacc44fa497996830214a0880',
        ClientSecret: '9731ecf36d1141d685587368b9237b22'
    }
}

export default { Credentials };
```

The Image [TypeError: Object(...) is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc8ng.png)

Comment: you need to export as named export . you can export like 'export const Cresentials =()=>{}'

Answer (score 0):

You're actually exporting an `object` containing your `function` as a default export .. and you're most likely importing it like:
`import Credentials from 'your/path';` ... and `Credentials` here is not a `function`, it's an `object`... which explains the error saying **Object(…) is not a function**

If you wanna have a **default export** like

```
export default Credentials;
```

You're gonna need to import it like:

```
import Credenitals from 'your/path';
```

Answer (score 0):

In *Credentials.js* you can export one function

```js
export const Credentials = () => {
```

instead of default export

```js
export default { Credentials }
```

Answer (score 0):

use import Credentials from '../ yourPath' above your code